# Angular's $interval service not found when testing using karma and mocha

Tags: angularjs, karma-mocha

I created a service that has $interval as a dependency and makes use of it and seems to work. Unfortunately when I'm trying to unit test the app $interval service is not found by angular:

```
Unknown provider: $$qProvider <- $$q <- $interval
```

I am not calling the service inside a controller as usual, but on the run() method of the app:

```
app.service('myService', ['$rootScope', '$window', '$interval', myService]);
app.run(function (myService) {
...
});
```

It works, but if I try to test the app crashes. Rest of angular services don't seem to have this problem ($window, $location, $rootScope, ...) and even this same service works if I attach my service to a controller instead than calling it at app.run():

```
app.controller('myController', ['myService', function(myService){ ... }]);
```

I use Karma+Mocha+Sinon+Chai to test.

**UPDATE**
Example with mini app trying to use $interval at app.run():

```
var anApp = angular.module('myTestApp', ['ngRoute']);
anApp.run(function($rootScope, $timeout, $window, $location, $interval) {
    // blah
});
```

The test:

```
describe("Lalarala", function() {
    var scope = null;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module("myTestApp");
        inject(function ($rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
        });
    });

    it("doesnt crash", function () {
        //blah
    });
});
```

**Note**: If you remove $interval from the app.run() it works. Instead, other angular services like $timeout, $window or $location don't seem to bother.

Also, I've noticed that other services like $resource have this problem too.

I presume some of those services require something else to be there before they are ready and that's why I can't call them at app.run()?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you share definition of `myService`?

Comment: Yes, I've added it now.

Comment: What do you mean by instantiating a service in `run()`? Also which line gives the error?

Comment: Also why did you hide some parameters of `inject` handler?

Comment: Because the real code is much longer and I thought would distract anyone from the real problem as it has too many dependencies. I have already filtered as to know which one of them is the one causing the issue and when, and as the other angular libraries don't have this problem I suppose this library has something different and maybe someone would know what it is.

Comment: Let me add more of the real code if that helps, but I'm quite sure the problem is on that library being called at app.run(). I am also using that library on another Service, that other service is a dependency of a controller and has no issues, so the problem happens when the service is called at app.run() instead than on a controller. But this only happens if I'm using $interval in the Service, doesn't happen with $rootScope, $window or others.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to use any service, just by calling $interval on the app.run() as a dependency makes the test fail. Give me a few minutes to write down an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

After checking many things I found the problem had to do with an angular-mocks being out of date.

I updated versions of angular and angular-mocks and now everything is working fine.

Sorry!

Comment: I'm glad the issue is resolved. Mind to accept the answer for convenience of future readers

Answer (score 1):

This line is definitely wrong.

> app.controller('myController', [myService, function(myService){ ... }]);

Array injection syntax should contain strings

```
 app.controller('myController', ['myService', function(myService){ ... }]);
```

Comment: Sorry that's because I didn't write the real code here but an example, you are right, the real code has it right though so this isn't the problem.